# Test for diagonalizability and find a basis for $V=M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ and $T$ is defined by $T(A)=A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the following linear operators T on a vector space V, test T for diagonalizability, and if T is diagonalizable, find a basis $\beta$ for V such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

$V=M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ and $T$ is defined by $T(A)=A^t$

I'm sorry but i have no idea where to begin with this. I'm supposed to show that the characteristic polynomial of T splits and check the eigenvalues multiplicity.

I do know that the diagonals of A and A^t are the same. and I have proven that the eigenvalues are $+1$ and $-1$. But this is where I'm stuck.

I suppose a possible set for $\beta=\{
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0\end{array} \right)\}$

Is this correct? But what is another possible set?
What about an ordered basis for $n>2$?

Furthermore how do i proceed to find the diagonal matrix $[T]_\beta$ and $Q$ that diagonializes A?

Comment: Since you're trying to diagonalize a transformation, you want a basis of "eigenvectors", which is to say in this case, "eigenmatrices". Your first two elements of $\beta$ are eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $+1$.  What do eigenvectors for $-1$ look like?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well that's the issue i'm having. I can't seem to see it when it comes to matrices. When i'm working with column basis it seems rather straight forward. Adding with the unknown A, I'm even more confused. Furthermore, the answer given below for the diag is a 4x4 matrix. How is that possible when $M_{2\times 2}$

Comment: Ok i figured out why it's a 4x4 matrix. Because the source space has dim 4 and the target space has dim 4 as well. I'm think that eigenvectors for $-1$ looks like anti-symmetric matrices? if thats the case, is $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\end{array} \right)$ a possible eigenvector for +1?

Comment: The matrix you just wrote is *not* antisymmetric. But yes: the antisymmetric matrices are your missing eigenvectors.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry lost my head there. So something like 
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0\end{array} \right)$ and
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\end{array} \right)$? I can only think of these 2 possibilities. Or must the coefficients not necessarily be +1 or -1? 
Furthermore how do I construct the diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $TA = \lambda A$, then $\lambda A = A^T$ and hence $A = \lambda A^T  = \lambda^2 A$, hence $\lambda = \pm 1$.

If $\lambda =1$, then **any** $A$ that satisfies $A = A^T$ is an eigenvector.
It is not too difficult to see that the eigenspace $\ker (T-I)$ has dimension
$3$ and to develop a basis.

If $\lambda = -1$, then $A = -A^T$, and it is not too difficult to see that
$\ker (T+I)$ is one dimensional.

Hence $T$ is diagonalisable, and $[T]_\beta$ has the form
$\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,-1)$ or some permutation thereof.

Comment: how did you get dig(1,1,1,-1)? why is there only one "-1" in the diag?

Comment: Since $\dim \ker (T-I) = 3$ and $\dim \ker (T+I) = 1$, we see that $T$ has a full basis of eigenvectors. In this basis, $T$ must be diagonal. Since $\dim \ker (T+I) = 1$, there is only one $-1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: suppose I choose diag(-1,1,1,1) instead, will it have a different basis from diag(1,1,1,-1)?

Comment: Well, you choose the basis first and then figure out the matrix representation. If you reorder the basis, you will reorder the eigenvalues accordingly.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how do I relate the basis to the diag matrix.
Suppose I use the basis $\beta=\{
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\end{array} \right) \} $

Comment: If you have a basis of eigenvectors $v_1,...,v_n$ and corresponding eigenvectors $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ (which may be repeated) then since $T v_k = \lambda_k v_k$ then in the basis $v_1,...,v_n$ then operator $T$ has the representation $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$. As an aside, note that $\beta$ cannot be a basis as the $4$th element is just the negative of the $3$rd element. You can find another matrix that satisfies $TX = X$.